Can't get id_token with Auth0 backend
I'm currently implementing the Auth0 OAuth2 backend in python-social-auth and social-app-django. At the start of the social-core pipeline, after I log into Auth0, I get an error during Auth0OAuth2.get_user_details() at jwt.decode(): DecodeError at /complete/auth0/: Invalid token type. Token must be a <class 'bytes'>. I've pasted that code below:
 def get_user_details(self, response):
        # Obtain JWT and the keys to validate the signature
        id_token = response.get("id_token")
        jwks = self.get_json(self.api_path(".well-known/jwks.json"))
        issuer = self.api_path()
        audience = self.setting("KEY")  # CLIENT_ID
        ...
        signature_error = None
        for key in keys:
            try:
                payload = jwt.decode(
                    id_token,
                    key.key,
                    algorithms=["RS256"],
                    audience=audience,
                    issuer=issuer,
                )

I assume the error is because response.get("id_token") is always None; the response argument only has keys for access_token, expires_at, and token_type. I must be missing something in my setup, but there's no documentation for the Auth0 backend in python-social-auth, so I'm not sure what could be wrong.
I have the following environment vars set:
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN

My Auth0 app is a Regular Web App on a developer account, and changing the app's grant types and authentication method hasn't fixed the error.
